# How to create a dynamic array with 2 different data types

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I need to create a dynamic array with data from a Excel spreadsheet using Apache-POI and Selenium.

My goal is to be able to create a dynamic array with 2 data types(int and String's)to be called to be inputted into a text field using Selenium WebDriver. I have already gotten the information to be hardcoded, however I'd like to be able to not rely on the workbook to increase the speed of my program.

General structure:

`for(int i = 0; i < sheet1.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
    string cell[i] = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(0)
}`

The errors I get are, "Syntax Error on token "i", delete this token" and also "Type mismatch: Cannot convert from "String" to "String[]"

Comment: string cell[i] just looks wrong... try removing 'string'

Answer (score 0):

Would it work if you stored everything in the array as a string? You could just use `String.valueOf()` to convert the cell value to a string, and if you need to get it back later on as an int you could use `Integer.parseInt()`.

You can make an array of Objects, but that could cause more trouble than it's worth. You could be adding an object into it which has a type you never accounted for, which could cause you problems later on down the line.

Comment: Well that's where the 'formatter.formatCellValue(sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(0)' comes into play, if I use any type of data is should just be allowed to be entered into the text field. If I do the array of Objects if there is a type I didn't account for the formatter would just make it into something that  will essentially become a string.

Comment: Ah, OK. I didn't know what it did exactly. I assumed that it just parsed the value into the appropriate format (string, int, double, datetime, etc).